# Writing RestAssured logs to StringWriter always seems to cut the last lines of the result

Tags: java, rest-assured, printstream, stringwriter

I am running RestAssured tests and I wanted to read info about the request from the logs ( to use in reports). I have a superclass with the following code which the test classes extent.
The superclass:

```
import java.io.PrintStream;
import java.io.StringWriter;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import io.restassured.filter.log.RequestLoggingFilter;
 

 static StringWriter requestWriter;
 static PrintStream requestCapture;
 requestWriter = new StringWriter();
 requestCapture = new PrintStream(new WriterOutputStream(requestWriter,
                StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
 filters(new RequestLoggingFilter(requestCapture)
```

```
system.out.println(requestWriter.toString())
```

Gives something like this:

```
Request method: GET
Request URI:    https://xxxxxxxxxxxxx/rest/v1/filters/4b54309a-37f0-11ec-8104-0af82ae7751a/tasks
Proxy:          <none>
Request params: <none>
Query params:   <none>
Form params:    <none>
Path params:    <none>
Headers:        Accept=*/*
                Content-Type=application/json
Cookies:        SESSION=869fd661-b0c8-408f-be33-db8951804ef3;Path=/cc;Secure;HttpOnly;SameSite=None
Multiparts:     <none>
Body:           <none>
Request method: GET
Request URI:    https://xxxxxxxxxx/rest/v1/tasks/cee718c1-8822-11ec-89f9-e27daa79f45a
Proxy:          <none>
Request params: <
```

where the logs are always missing the last lines, no matter how big or small it is.

Answer (score 0):

It looks a lot like a missing `flush()` call.

The easiest solution is to set the autoFlush parameter to `true` when constructing your `PrintStream`:

```
new PrintStream(true, new WriterOutputStream(requestWriter, UTF_8))
```